# Tomcat Still Displaying :8080 after configuration changes

Tags: tomcat, configuration

I looked around the site and tried to follow the recommendations. I specified that Tomcat use port 80, changed the connector listening port, and restarted the server each time. However, when I try to access port http://www.powdernow.com:8080/avyproject/ I can only do so by specifying :8080. How can I get rid of the port number from the url? the url is registered.

I am using a virtual machine with Centos 6 and Tomcat 7.

My httpd is set to listen at port 80 with Listen 80 and I tried Listen :80 after removing the 8080 specification.

I ran some commands at the request of others and here are the responses:

ps -ef |egrep '(httpd|apache)' yields a path to /usr/share with the following full output

```
 root      1987     1 99 May04 ?        135-02:08:33 nano /var/log/httpd/error_log
tomcat   14306     1  0 21:38 pts/1    00:00:20 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.53 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.53 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     17422 13410  0 22:15 pts/1    00:00:00 egrep (httpd|apache)
```

/usr/sbin/httpd -S yields the following error.

```
Syntax error on line 89 of /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-63-141-236.ip.secureserver.net/conf/14000506980.07205400_httpd_ip_default.include:
Wrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper cannot be accessed: (2)No such file or directory
```

The result of netstat -anp | egrep '(:8080|:80)'

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17519/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17519/java
```

I am incredibly new to using servers and this is my first Spring application. If this is Tomcat, is there a command I can run to find the configuration file? I left this for several months.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/sbin/httpd` and `httpd.conf` are for [Apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/), which is a completely different program from Tomcat.  Tomcat is generally configured with a file called `context.xml`.  It sounds like you're configuring the wrong program.

If you have both Tomcat and httpd installed on the same machine, note that httpd runs on port 80 by default, so Tomcat won't be able to listen on that port if httpd is already running.  It sounds like your httpd is failing to start due to syntax error in its configuration file, which would mean that it's not occupying port 80, but having a broken httpd configuration isn't really a good solution to the conflict.  If you're not using httpd, you should probably just uninstall it.

(This tends to be a confusing topic because Apache httpd and Apache Tomcat are both web servers developed by the Apache Software Foundation, and Apache httpd is often referred to as just "Apache".  When someone refers to "Apache" as the name of a program, they mean httpd, not Tomcat.)

Comment: quick question. IF i do not have etc/defaults/tomcat7. Is there a way to install it so that my server notices it or is there a way to figure out the config? I changed context and still have an issue.

Comment: ok so i edited server.xml and forwarded traffic from port 80 to 8082 (completely open to avoid a postgresql conflict). that seems like a temporary fix is there a better way of doing this? I also do not have /etc/defaults/tomcat7 since I had to install tomcat in a pretty strange way